# Metal enclosure insulating paint/spray

Tags: electrical-panel

What spray or paint can you use to insulate metal enclosure from conduction (say in breaker panel just for double protection in case the breaker won't open during ground fault to case)?

Comment: electrical conduction.. will do it to breaker panel

Comment: are you saying that the case is not properly grounded? .... it is unclear why it would need to be insulated

Comment: Just for double protection.

Answer (score 1):

### [Glyptal](http://www.matweb.com/search/GetMatlsByManufacturer.aspx?manID=1049)

*It was invented by GE for literally that purpose*. It's for painting metal parts of electrical motors, rotating equipment and cabinets.

Aside from superlative electrical insulation, it has good thermal performance and low flammability.   This has resulted in *off-label* use to seal engine blocks.

Don't paint parts of the panel that are not meant to be painted. It may be most expedient to protect the bus assembly by pulling it out entirely for painting.

Comment: How tough is the Glyptal? If you apply it on any metal enclosure, how thick is the insulation and is it so tough you can't even remove it with knife?

Comment: @Jtl **It is paint**. So no.   If you want an insulating service that's knife proof, try sending it out and having it porcelain enameled, like a clawfoot tub would be. But I really have no idea what the dielectric strength of enamel is.  Also, if you are doing anything with metal conduit that involves the conduit being a ground path, the wrong coating will break it.